# Can I pay an ex-relative not to use my family name and make it stick

Tags: united-states, family-law, divorce, georgia

I would prefer that my ex-daughter-in-law not use my family name as hers.  The divorce decree says she may do so.  She is motivated by money, so may be interested in changing her last name for a price.

My question is, Will it stick.  Is it possible to structure a legal arrangement with her to forbid her from changing her name back after a short (or long) time has passed?  (This is in the state of Georgia, in the USA.)

A monetary penalty will not be effective, since she has no funds and already has various creditors, some with priority.

Comment: Not a full answer, but I don't think jail time (really the only other penalty option) would be on the table for breach of contract, which is what this would amount to.

Comment: Are you attached to the idea of a one time payment?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt. Hmm. Spaced payments.  Sounds effective but perhaps more costly.

Comment: I've never seen it done in any case law or in real life. It isn't obviously prohibited, but I wouldn't put money on how a challenge to such an order would come out. I can see plausible arguments for invalidating such an agreement as void as against public policy (e.g. will and trust provisions conditioning inheritances upon getting married are void as contrary to public policy, even if they don't say who you must marry). Such a deal is arguably contrary to the best interests of the children (if any) and you really have no legitimate reason to make her change her name.